# React JSX Component and Await

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await, jsx

I have an async/await function of which I want to use the result to conditionally render a jsx component in my React native application.

This a class method that returns a promise.  The method has async declared.

The problem is I want to use the result of this to conditionally render some jsx.

```js
const hasEdit = await perms.has('/page', 'edit');

return (
      <div>
      { hasEdit &&
        <Button
          icon='pencil'
          text='EDIT'
          onTouchTap={ () => { props.onEdit(); } }
        />
      }
      </div>
    )
```

This returns:
*A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.*

Any idea how I can attempt this?  Anything would be appreciated.

Comment: `render` must not be asynchronous.

Comment: put that async call in `componentDidMount` and save the result to react state

Comment: Same deal if using redux?  push the result to the react state and use it in render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion of moving componentDidMount, making it async and then setState on the result makes it available in render.  Render can not be async.