# What happens if we call an async function inside render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

We do not use redux or saga and use services instead, for making API calls and storing data. Consider that there is a button that will make an async call when clicked.

1. Is it safe to call the async function inside the render method?
2. Would it make the UI unresponsive until the promise is resolved?

```
render() {
    return (
        <Button onPress={() => {await this.requestOtp()}} text="Get OTP" />
    );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React JSX Component and Await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659360/react-jsx-component-and-await)

Comment: You're not calling the async method in the render function. It is called in the `onPress` callback, which should be fine.

Comment: @zero298 the title of this question looks like the dupe, but it's really not a dupe, unless OP changes the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent(){

 let [output, updateOutput] = useState(null);

 async function asyncFunction(){

  // call here
  let response = await this.requestOtp();
  updateOutput(response.data);

 }

 return <Button onPress={asyncFunction} text={output} />

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Render can not be async you can pass the async to componentDidMount or use hooks